# Livewire: How can I reset an object property?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to do something simple using the `reset()` method.

My `url` model (object) has a `title` property, which binds to an input field on my blade:

```
<input
  type="text"
  wire:model.lazy="url.title"
  wire:keydown.escape="reset_fields"
  ...
```

In my `reset_fields` function I have:

```
public function reset_fields()
{
  $this->reset('url.title');
}
```

The error it displays is:

```
Livewire\Exceptions\PropertyNotFoundException
Property [$url.title] not found on component: [url-row]
```

The workaround I found is the following:

```
<input
  type="text"
  wire:model.lazy="title"
  wire:keydown.escape="reset_fields"
  ...
```

In the component I have:

```
...
public $title;
...

public function mount() {
  $this->title = $this->url->title;
}

public function reset_fields() {
  $this->mount();
}
```

So yeah, it works, but I think that's not the "correct way". So my question is, how do I use the `reset()` method, and if it is possible to use it with objects

Answer (score 0):

when binding directly to model properties like 'url.title' you should declare the model-property in rules like

```
public Url $url;
protected $rules = [
  'url.title' => 'required'
];
....
public function reset_fields()
{
   $this->url->title = null;
}

// blade
<input
  type="text"
  wire:model.lazy="url.title"
  wire:keydown.escape="reset_fields">
```